# How can i validate phone numbers based on country in zend framework 2

Tags: validation, zend-framework2

I am working with a Trekking website and i have used Zend Framework 2. Any visitor for this site can book Trekking Packages from any country. So my client wants Phone number validation based on country. 
So, i have gone through research and till not found a perfect solution. It would be a great help if any one can help me solving this Phone No. validation work.

Comment: Kindly share your research/coding effort, to help us guide you better.

Comment: pls show us your "not so perfect" solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need the intl php extention in order for this to work.

After reading the class PhoneNumber.php under Zend\I18n\Validator. I came up with this.

$post is the form post where the user sends country e.g. GB, the country code e.g. 44, 0044, +44, and the phone number. if i remember correctly the class handles 00 and + but you should confirm.

> $phone = new \Zend\I18n\Validator\PhoneNumber();//phone validation
>   $phone->setCountry($post->country);//set the country (e.g CY)
>
> switch ($post) {
>
> case !$phone->isValid($post->phone_country_code.$post->phone,
>   array('national'))://check if country and phone are valid
>
> $msg = 'The Phone you Entered is Not valid. Please check the country
>   code and phone and try again.';
>
> break;
>
> default:
>
> $msg=null;
>
> break; }